# Adding variable to InAppBrowser URL

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

would like to ask how can I add a variable or parameter on my InAppBrowser url? {{id}} doesn't seem to be readable in the URL when clicked opened although as a text typescript it works.

My code for the button is as follows,

```html
<ion-button expand="full" fill="solid" color="primary" (click)="
openWithSystemBrowser('https://wa.me/123456789?text=Hi! My domain and keywords details for Order #{{id}} are as follows...')">
{{ 'Notify Us' | translate }}
</ion-button>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show how the url looks like in the browser? You should try to use string interpolation like this : `open(\`Some text with ${variable}\`) `

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should be using:

```
<ion-button expand="full" fill="solid" color="primary" (click)="
openWithSystemBrowser(`https://wa.me/123456789?text=Hi! My domain and keywords details for Order #${id} are as follows...`)">
{{ 'Notify Us' | translate }}
</ion-button>
```

I've switch the ' ' around the url to backticks.

I've also swapped your `{{ }}` notation to string interprolation `${id}`